# Get the Cross Entropy Loss in pytorch as in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I am struggling to port a classification model form keras to pytorch. Especially the cross entropy loss seems to return totally different numbers.

````py
import numpy as np
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

y_true = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
y_pred = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 0.41, 0.31, 0.21, 0.11]])

print("Keras", K.categorical_crossentropy(K.constant(y_true), K.constant(y_pred)))
print("PyTorch", nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(t.tensor(y_pred).argsort(dim=-1).float(), t.tensor(y_true).argmax(dim=-1)))```
````

prints:

> Keras tf.Tensor([2.3369865], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
>
> PyTorch tensor(1.4587)

Since I have a custom loss function where cross entropy is a part of it, I would need to get similar if not the same numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that they have different implementations.

As pytorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) says, `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` combines `nn.LogSoftmax()` and `nn.NLLLoss()` in one single class. However, tensorflow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/categorical_crossentropy) specifies that `keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy` do not apply Softmax by default unless you set `from_logits` is True. For this reason, you should not use `keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy` without having previously apply softmax unless you use `from_logits=True`.

If you don't want to apply softmax beforehand you should use:

```
import numpy as np
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

y_true = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
y_pred = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 0.41, 0.31, 0.21, 0.11]])


print("Keras", K.categorical_crossentropy(K.constant(y_true), K.constant(y_pred), from_logits=True))
# output: Keras tf.Tensor([2.408051], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
print("PyTorch", nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(t.tensor(y_pred).float(), t.tensor(y_true).argmax(dim=-1)))
# output: PyTorch tensor(2.4081)
```

Otherwise, you can apply Softmax manually before computing categorical_crossentropy

```
import numpy as np
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

y_true = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
y_pred = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 0.41, 0.31, 0.21, 0.11]])


print("Keras", K.categorical_crossentropy(K.constant(y_true), K.softmax(K.constant(y_pred))))
# output: Keras tf.Tensor([2.408051], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
print("PyTorch", nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(t.tensor(y_pred).float(), t.tensor(y_true).argmax(dim=-1)))
# output: PyTorch tensor(2.4081)
```

So you should not use `keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy` with `from_logits=False` as you were doing in your example.

> **tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy**
>
> **target**:   A tensor of the same shape as output.
>
> **output**:   A tensor resulting from a softmax (unless from_logits is True, in which case output is expected to be the logits).
>
> **from_logits**:  Boolean, whether output is the result of a softmax, or is a tensor of logits.

Comment: So if I go for option 2, then my last operation in the pytorch model need to be a Softmax right? Because Keras actually checks if the last operation was softmax or not https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f36a1a090e469c632448722186a26a416fda4596/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4591

Comment: Not really, pytorch apply softmax by default so you don't need to use softmax in your model. With keras you need to apply softmax if from_logits=False. Otherwise, if from_logits=True, it acts as pytorch function.